# Textview for url ellipsize

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that displays a URL. The problem is:-

If the url is very long it will flow into multiple lines. I have tried setting `maxlines`, `setSingleLine` and `ellipsize` but they have all not worked. For a `TextView` that holds a single long "word", is it still possible to cut it off if it exceeds a single line?

Answer (score 0):

use this
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"